# How to load matlab 3D matrix into Avizo Lite 9.1.1

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have a MATLAB 3D matrix of dimensions  2001*2001*291, which represent a function f=f(x,y,z). The matrix is sroed in a .mat file.

I want to create an impressive 3D figure out of it.

The following link recommends on Avizo: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66740-plot-a-function-with-3-variables  .

In Avizo's tutorial it is written that the software supports import of MATLAB .mat files. However, using the  File/Open Data or  File/Open Data as... menue and selecting MATLAB mat-file, cause nothing to happen.

Does anybody knows how to present MATLAB .mat file data in Avizo ???

I'd appreciate any help !!

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you should do.

1. Enable console in avizo (project window)
2. Click open data in project window and open the .mat file.
3. See the message on the console. The error is most likely due to inability to load matlab engine. Therefore,
4. in windows' start menu type `PATH`, click on edit environmental variables for your account. Click new, type `PATH` in variable name and copy paste the path for matlabs' `\bin\win64`. For example, `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64`. click OK OK.
5. the connection with matlab is now done, restart AVIZO
   Now the .mat file can load!!